# Windows Phone App certification failed due Malware detected when using Nokia Ad Exchange

Tags: windows-phone-7, nokia, ads

I recently signed up on Nokia Ad Exchange, I decided to use their service on my Windows Phone Apps. So I updated those apps to use Nokia Ad service, but now all of them are failing certification because "Malware was detected".

I know that most of you will suggest to drop this service, but I honestly would like to find a solution for this.

Thanks,

Comment: How do you know what it considers to be malware? I don't really believe it's Nokia Ad Exchange.

Comment: Well I am 100% sure it's not my code. My app passed certification when I used PubCenter...

Comment: To be fair, it could be a third-party providing a Malicious Ad. My question is how Nokia doesn't catch this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion was correct, a third-party was providing a malicious Ad. Nokia already handled it. If this happens to you, just resubmit the app.